# Copying objects in React-Redux reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm rank new to React and even newer to Redux thus the question.

So I have an initial state in my reducer which is `Object = {}`

Now I want to modify this state and return it with an object user.

So I'm expecting a result `Object = {user}`

User in itself has the following properties,

```
{A: 1, B:2, C:3}
```

If I use `Object.assign({}, state, user}`
 I get the following,

```
Object = {A: 1, B:2, C:3}
```

So how do I copy the user object to the state object as a parameter without splitting it up. Also how do I do this in case the object I'm adding is an array.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by splitting it up - can you add the object that you would like the store to be?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead: `Object.assign({}, state, {user})`

EDIT: Responding to your comment below, if user was an array, say `users`, it would work the same:

```
> var state = {A: 1, B:2, C:3}
> var users = [1,2,3];
> Object.assign({}, state, {users});
{A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, users: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

Comment: hehe, just beat me to it!

Comment: Now how can I do this, when the object I'm adding is an array?

Comment: @StochasticNerd you can have a look at the this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040102/remove-element-from-nested-redux-state/40049559#40049559

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Object.assign({}, state, { user: user })
```

Reason:

The objects you are passing in will overwrite the previous options, by passing in user, you are overwriting the current state with {A: 1, B:2, C:3} rather than overwriting the property in the object with the keyid user.

---

Alternatively (and if your setup supports it), you can use spread syntax as follows:

```
{
  ...state,
  user: user
}
```

actually, even shorter,

```
{
  ...state,
  user 
}
```

`Object.assign` is overkill for Redux.