# Updating array in redux State

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

how to update and element in an Array in REDUX state 
for

```
var initialState = {
   DataArray :[],
   isSelected : flase,
}
```

Ex:

```
var DataArray = [
               {place:NY ,Bool:true},
               {place:Boston ,Bool:true}
              ]
```

updated to

```
var DataArray =[
            {place:NY ,Bool:false},
            {place:Boston ,Bool:true},
           ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040102/remove-element-from-nested-redux-state/40049559#40049559

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#updating-an-item-in-an-array

Comment: ya i tried this one @HarkiratSaluja

Comment: it didnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my below code. May b It will help you. 
Use this code in your reducer, where you want to update data in array.

```
return { ...state,
      stateArray: state.stateArray.map(data => {
        if (data.place === action.payload.data.place) {
          return action.payload.data;
        }
        else {
          return {place:data.place,count:data.count,selected:false};
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have object in payload you want to update and your action type is `UPDATE_ARRAY`

```
case 'UPDATE_ARRAY':
  let data = [...state.DataArray],
  index = data.findIndex(r => r.place === action.payload.place) //finding which index should get the udpate
  if(index > -1) //
  {
    data[index] = action.payload
    return {...state,DataArray: data}
    // ES5 --> return Object.assign({},state,DataArray: data)
  }
  else return state
```